# How I can extend max time given to perform dart2js in WebStorm

Tags: dart, webstorm, dart2js

I have a big Dart project with a compilation time longer than the 30s allowed by WebStorm. Is there any way to extend allowed calculation time?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure, but you may want to file a feature request: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-12835#newissue=yes

Comment: You could build in a terminal using the `pub build` command.

Comment: I'm not sure what 30s timeout are you talking about. There are no compilation timeouts in WebStorm. Can you please paste a screenshot?

Comment: Dart2js is external tool, so it is performed like a script called from WebStorm. In long term, the solution could be SSD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This 30s timeout comes from the dart2js tool, not from the IDE.
By the way AFAIK direct dart2js usage is not a recommended workflow. Dart2js option is removed from Dart Editor context menu and will be removed from WebStorm as well. Instead you should use [pub build](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/cmd/pub-build.html). In WebStorm 'pub build' option is available in context menu of the pubspec.yaml file and also in the editor with pubspec.yaml file open.